# How to get httpcontext session value using jmeter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, jmeter

i can not get *httpcontext session* value through *jmeter*, how could i get session values from controller session through jmeter. can any one help!

```
variable: sessionid
regular expression: Set-Cookie:(,+?);
template: $1$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this using Regular Expression Extractor:

1. Use `Response Headers` as the "Field to Check"
2. Amend your regular expression to look like:

   ```
   Set-Cookie: (.*)
   ```

However this approach will give you **full** contents of the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header, not only the value but also domain, path, expires, secure, httponly attributes.

If you want to get the value of a single cookie into a JMeter Variable the easiest way is:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
4. That's it, now you can access any cookie value using the following pattern:

   ```
   ${COOKIE__your cookie name here}
   ```

   so if you have cookie named `sessionid` you can read its value as `${COOKIE__sessionid}`

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/)